# convert the strings in my list to a list c#

Tags: c#, string, list

i'm quite new to this, i already did a little c# in unity, but never really in VS.

I have a txt file that looks approximatively like this :

monday;8;server1,server2,server3

tuesday;9;server3,server4

wedneday;8;server1,server2,server4

i splitted this into 3 list, one with the day (monday)... one with the hour (8)... and one with the servers(server1,server2,server3), but i would like to convert this server string into unique lists,

for example i would like a list1 to contain all servers to of monday (server1,server2,server3), a list2 to contain all servers of tuesday (server3,server4).

These servers names are splitted with a comma, and i would like to split every string into a
unique list

i know i was not very clear, please ask for any specifications

```
List<string> plages_horaires_ouverture = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt").ToList();


        foreach (var fileLine in plages_horaires_ouverture)
        {
            var splitLignes = fileLine.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            
            listeJoursOuverture.Add(splitLignes[0]);
            listeHeuresOuverture.Add(splitLignes[1]);
            listeServeursOuverture.Add(splitLignes[2]);


        }
```

this code splits the txt file into 3 separate lists containing strings, and now i would like to convert every element (string) of the list "listeServeursOuverture" (sorry for the french name) into a unique list. Every element in this list looks like this "server1,server2,server4" or "server2,server3" and is separated with a comma

Any ideas? I tried many things but none worked, this question is certainly stupid, and im sorry for that

Leno

Comment: How about doing a second split on `","`? But now your data has a bit more structure it may be worthwhile creating a model object appropriate to the data.

Comment: Not sure what's stopping you. You certainly can split the servers by comma just as you did the whole line by semicolon. I _guess_ you are having trouble figuring out, where to put those. It looks as if you just put everything in lists. So in any `listXXXOverture[index]`, `index` would tell you which entry you are referencing. So, why not make a Model class and put _that_ in a List or Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Use [List.AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0):

```
List<String> servers = new List<String>();
servers.AddRange(splitLignes[2].Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spreading your data into different Lists, I'd have *one* List (or at least some kind of DataStructure. You may later find a Dictionary helpful, maybe).

In that List, I'd have instances of a Model class like for example this one:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string Day {get; set;}
   public int Hour {get; set;}
   public List<string> Servers {get; set;} = new List<string>();
}
```

Then you can look up the Server Lists by Day as you want if I read the question correctly.

Populating may go something like this:

```
foreach (var fileLine in plages_horaires_ouverture)
{
    var splitLignes = fileLine.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    
    var model = new MyModel{
        Day = splitLignes[0],
        Hour = int.Parse(splitLignes[1].Trim())
    };
    model.Servers.AddRange(splitLignes[2].Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None));

    listeOverture.Add(model);

    // don't need these anymore.        
    // listeJoursOuverture.Add(splitLignes[0]);
    // listeHeuresOuverture.Add(splitLignes[1]);
    // listeServeursOuverture.Add(splitLignes[2]);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, your solution looks great! I just have two errors , the first one is saying "the name Servers does not exist in the actual context" CS0103 and the second one CS0747 saying "Invalid initializer member declarator." it is weird because the public string day and hour work great in the model... any solutions? And im so thankful ^^

Comment: Ah, I didn't test. I guess the AddRange may be a problem. Will adapt the code ...

Comment: OHHH!!! I was so stupid! of  course this list "listeOuverture" needed to be a MyModel list and not a string, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary here:

```
    List<string> plages_horaires_ouverture = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt").ToList();

    Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>,List<string>> servers = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>,List<string>>
    foreach (var fileLine in plages_horaires_ouverture)
    {
        var splitLignes = fileLine.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        
        KeyValuePair<string, string> key = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(splitLignes[0], splitLignes[1]);
        List<string> serversForDay = splitLignes[2].Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        servers.Add(key, serversForDay);
    }
```

Comment: instead of a KeyValuePair you could convert your text into a Date item as well. That might make more sense if you can guarantee it's parseable.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the names and the types as needed. Make a class object to sort the data as you like, then make a method that returns a list of that class. This is more clear for you when you need to deal with your code later.

```cs
public List<DataModel> GetListFromData()
        {

            List<string> plages_horaires_ouverture = File.ReadAllLines( @"file.txt" ).ToList();

            List<DataModel> list = new List<Dd>();
            foreach ( var fileLine in plages_horaires_ouverture )
            {
                var splitLignes = fileLine.Split(  ";" , StringSplitOptions.None );

                List<string> d = splitLignes[0].Split( "," ).ToList();
                List<string> h =splitLignes[1].Split( "," ).ToList();
                List<string> s =splitLignes[2].Split( "," ).ToList();
                list.Add( new DataModel( d , h[0] , s ) );
              
            }
            return list;
        }
        class DataModel
        {
            public DataModel( List<string> days,string hour  , List<string> servers )
            {
                Hour = hour;
                Days = days;
                Servers = servers;
            }

            public string Hour { get; set; }
            public List<string> Days { get; set; }
            public List<string> Servers { get; set; }
        }
```